# Is it possible to insert a gif in the Dev Express Grid Designer?

Tags: c#, devexpress, gif

I'm trying to insert a gif into a column in the Grid Designer of Dev Express.

I currently use DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ImageComboBoxItemCollection (Image Collection) but the gif doesn't work.

Any suggestions or alternatives?

I'm expecting that associated with a value it returns the gif, for now it's only works with jpg or png...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.